# Process activated function in MySQLi?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Trying to initiate a function in PHP and MySQLi to return TRUE if the user is activated (1) or FALSE is the user is NOT activated (0).

I have tested these codes out and have had no luck, getting MySQLi errors. And bare in mind, I am new to MySQLi.

```
function get_activated($mysqli, $userid) {

    $row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '{$userid}' AND activated = '1'")->fetch_array();
    if($row){
        $activated = TRUE;
        return $activated;
    }
}

function get_activated($mysqli) {

    $row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '{$userid}' AND activated = '1'")->fetch_array();
    if($row){
        $activated = TRUE;
        return $activated;
    }
}

function get_activated($mysqli, $userid) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
         $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '{$userid}' AND activated = '1'")->fetch_array();
    if($row){
        $activated = TRUE;
        return $activated;
    }
    }
}

function get_activated($mysqli) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
         $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $row = $mysqli->query("SELECT activated FROM users WHERE userid = '{$userid}'")->fetch_array();
    return $row["activated"];
    }
}
```

I am calling the function like this:

```
get_activated($userid);
                echo $activated;
                exit();

get_activated();
            echo $row['activated'];
            exit();
```

If anyone could point me on the right track here I'd be very appreciative, thanks!

Errors examples:

Missing argument 2 for get_activated()
Call to a member function query() on a non-object
Only variables should be passed by reference 
Missing argument 1 for get_activated()

Comment: Why do you have so many functions that are named the same? (`get_activated()`)? Also, when you `return` a variable, that is set to assign to something, not be called like you're trying...It should be like this: `$activated = get_activated($userid);`

Comment: show the mysqli error.

Comment: Please put the errors you're getting into the question.

Comment: **Another Note:** You should be checking if the query was successful, not just hoping it ran and fetching the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
function get_activated($mysqli, $userid) {
    $row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '$userid' AND activated = '1'")->fetch_array();
    if(!empty($row)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

the fetch_array() method is MySQLi will return null if it finds no rows, I just like using empty, incase you have exteneded MySQLi and somehow changed the functionality - I've done that before accidentally.

Also when you then call this function you should use -

```
$activated = get_activate($mysqli,1);
var_dump($activated);
```

On a side note, I would always use prepared statements, but thats not for this question.

Comment: Thanks very much! Worked first time, exactly what I was looking for - on a side note, where you have entered ($mysqli,1); to call the function, is that just telling it to call $userid? As in the old version of MySQL, I remember functions having variables sent through them such as the one in my question get_activated($userid); etc...

Comment: I was just giving an example userid, which I presumed was a 1, yeah you should use $userid.

Answer (score 1):

So let's take these one by one

```
function get_activated($mysqli, $userid) {

    $row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '{$userid}' AND activated = '1'")->fetch_array();
    if($row){
        $activated = TRUE;
        return $activated;
    }
}
```

So +1 for injecting the `mysqli` class but you are looking only at if the query succeeded. Remember, a query can succeed and return 0 rows. You also only `return` something if the query succeeds. You should return a `true` on success and `false` on no success.

Function #2 is confusing because it omits `$userid` and suffers from the same problems.

```
function get_activated($mysqli, $userid) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
         $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '{$userid}' AND activated = '1'")->fetch_array();
    if($row){
        $activated = TRUE;
        return $activated;
    }
    }
}
```

So now we have `$_SESSION` values but still pass `$userid` as an argument (which is confusing). We then look to see if the `query` returned any values. This is better but it's bad form to chain `query` to `fetch_*` because if the query fails you get a FATAL error.

```
function get_activated($mysqli) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
         $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $row = $mysqli->query("SELECT activated FROM users WHERE userid = '{$userid}'")->fetch_array();
    return $row["activated"];
    }
}
```

So same issue with `$userid` as #3 and same issue with chaining but we're closer, because we're returning a value at least. But, again, it doesn't consider what happens if the query returns 0 rows.

Let's write a full function that works now

```
function get_activated($mysqli, $userid) {
     $uid = $mysqli->real_escape_string($userid);
     $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = " . $uid . " AND activated = '1'");
     $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
     return ($data) ? true : false;
}
```

So, first we sanitize `$userid`. Then we do a query on it. Afterwards, we look for a returned row and we return a boolean if we did or didn't. Now we can use it like this

```
if(get_activated($mysqli, $userid)) {
    echo 'Activated';
} else {
    echo 'Not activated';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain in such detail to a newbie like myself, if more people helped in this way, us newbies would be experts in no time, I've learnt a lot reading through each example, will get back to work using your advice and experiment a little with it, I appreciate the help!